# hide / show menu & elements from component based on role & permission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I am working on one angular application implemented login as well. I have maintained menu-items.ts from which I am getting my all menus & looping through them & displaying them. I receive menu names & permission "READ/WRITE" in login. now I want to hide/show the menu & element from components based on role & permission. how can achieve the same?
kidly guide me.

```js
const MENUITEMS: IMenuItem[] = [
  {
    name: 'Admin',
    type: 'main',
    icon: 'apps',
    isActive: true,
    isMenuActive: false,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Admin Menu',
        type: 'sub-menu',
        isActive: false,
        isMenuActive: false,
        subchildren: [
          {
            state: 'admin-menu-listing',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: false,
            name: 'Admin Menu List',
          },
          {
            state: 'admin-menu-listing/add-menu',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: false,
            name: 'Add Admin Menu',
          },
          {
            state: 'admin-menu-listing/reorder-menu',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: false,
            name: 'Reorder Admin Menu',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Role',
        type: 'sub-menu',
        isActive: true,
        isMenuActive: false,
        subchildren: [
          {
            state: 'admin-roles',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Role List',
          },
          {
            state: 'admin-roles/add-role',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Add Role',
          },
          // {
          //   state: 'admin-roles/edit-menu-permission',
          //   type: 'sub-child-menu',
          //   isMenuActive: false,
          //   isActive: true,
          //   name: 'EDIT MENU PERMISSION',
          // },
          // {
          //   state: 'admin-roles/edit-module-permission',
          //   type: 'sub-child-menu',
          //   isMenuActive: false,
          //   isActive: true,
          //   name: 'EDIT MODULE PERMISSION',
          // },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'User',
        type: 'sub-menu',
        isActive: true,
        isMenuActive: false,
        subchildren: [
          {
            state: 'manage-user-listing',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'User List',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-user-listing/add-user',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Add User',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Workflow',
        type: 'sub-menu',
        isActive: true,
        isMenuActive: false,
        subchildren: [
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Workflow List',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing/add-workflow',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Add Workflow',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing/assigned-workflow-listing',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isActive: true,
            isMenuActive: false,
            name: 'Assigned Workflow List',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing/assign-workflow',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Assign Workflow',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing/map-workflow-listing',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Map Workflow List',
          },
          {
            state: 'manage-workflow-listing/add-map-workflow',
            type: 'sub-child-menu',
            isMenuActive: false,
            isActive: true,
            name: 'Map Workflow',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
 ]
 
 
 
 
 // roles & permission received from backend
 {"modulePermissionList":[{"moduleName":"MENU","permissionList":[{"permissionId":1,"permissionName":"READ"},{"permissionId":2,"permissionName":"WRITE"}]}],"user":{"id":12,"email":"test@neosoftmail.com","firstName":"Test ","lastName":"User"},"iat":1616482774,"exp":1616569174}
```

```html
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems.getAll()">
                <ul class="menu-level-one">
                  <li [ngClass]="{ 'active-one': item.isMenuActive }" (click)="onMainMenu(item)">
                    <a [routerLink]="item.state ? [item.state] : []" *ngIf="item.isActive">
                      {{ item.name }}
                      <mat-icon class="menu-caret" *ngIf="item.children">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item.children">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let child of item.children">
                        <ul class="menu-level-two">
                          <li [ngClass]="{ 'active-two': child.isMenuActive }" (click)="onSubMenu(child, $event)">
                            <a [routerLink]="child.state ? [child.state] : []" *ngIf="child.isActive">
                              {{ child.name }}
                              <mat-icon class="menu-caret" *ngIf="child.subchildren">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
                            </a>

                            <ng-container *ngIf="child.subchildren">
                              <ng-container *ngFor="let subChild of child.subchildren">
                                <ul class="menu-level-three">
                                  <li
                                    [ngClass]="{ 'active-three': subChild.isMenuActive }"
                                    (click)="onSubChildMenu(subChild, $event)"
                                  >
                                    <a [routerLink]="subChild.state ? [subChild.state] : []" *ngIf="subChild.isActive">
                                      {{ subChild.name }}
                                      <mat-icon class="menu-caret" *ngIf="subChild.subChildSubMenu"
                                        >arrow_drop_down</mat-icon
                                      >
                                    </a>
                                    <ng-container *ngIf="child.subchildren">
                                      <ul class="menu-level-four">
                                        <ng-container *ngFor="let subChildSub of subChild.subChildSubMenu">
                                          <li
                                            [ngClass]="{ 'active-four': subChildSub.isMenuActive }"
                                            (click)="onSubChildSubMenu(subChildSub, $event)"
                                          >
                                            <a
                                              [routerLink]="subChildSub.state ? [subChildSub.state] : []"
                                              *ngIf="subChildSub.isActive"
                                            >
                                              {{ subChildSub.name }}
                                            </a>
                                          </li>
                                        </ng-container>
                                      </ul>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your IMenuItem, add an attribute "role" and associate the values [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] as the role.

```
const MENUITEMS: IMenuItem[] = [
  {
    name: 'Admin',
    type: 'main',
    icon: 'apps',
    isActive: true,
    isMenuActive: false,
    roles: [ROLE_ADMIN]
    children: [
      {
        ...
```

In your html, use a directive like this one https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/shared/auth/has-any-authority.directive.ts to show or not the menu

`<li *hasAnyAuthority="ROLE_USER" ...`

Besides, don't forget authorities & routguard through your authentication system https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access :)

Answer (score 0):

If a user is never going to interact with menu items that they don't have permissions for, you could set up your service layer to filter out items based on the current users role.

Then no matter how many components pull in menu items, you only have to implement the logic once.